# how can I create a menuBar using tkinter in python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-menu

I really hope that you understand the following question, because I wasn't sure how to ask this question so I hope you can help me, if not let me now

I want to make a program to practise my python programming skill. I want to make a store program where an employee could input items with the price, and where he could sell the items. I want to make it that one “page” is the items input an another “page” is the sell page. To so that I want to make a menu bar where the employee could press on the let's say input button and go to input items page, but when he wants to sell items he presses on the sell button and then he goes to the sell page but only the screen changes, not that there comes another tab/window.

I really hope I explained my problem good enough

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Everything you want to do, you can learn to do with existing tutorials and documentation. What do you need our help? What _specifically_ do you need help with?

Comment: I googled for a long time on how to make a python application that has multiple “pages”, so if I press a button in the menu bar(what I don’t now how to make) I get a different page but without multiple windows but I didn’t find anything

Comment: Where can I look how to do such a thing?

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comments to the question, it appears your main problem is that you don't know how to make a menubar, so I will address that part of the question.

Every top level window (instances of `Tk` and `Toplevel`) have a `menu` attribute that can be set to an instance of a `Menu` object. This menu can itself have dropdown menus, and that combination is what makes a menubar.

In order to make this work you must first create the menu, and then associate that menu with the window.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
self.menubar = tk.Menu()
root.configure(menu=self.menubar)
```

To create the sub-menus you must do something very similar. First, create a new `Menu` instance, then associate it with the menubar using `add_cascade`. Typically, the menu will be a child of the menubar. You use the `add_command` method to add items to the sub-menu.

In your case, you might want to create a "View" menu with items for switching between "Input" and "Sell". It would look something like this:

```
viewMenu = tk.Menu(self.menubar)
self.menubar.add_cascade(label="View", menu=viewMenu)
viewMenu.add_command(label="Input", command=self.switch_to_input)
viewMenu.add_command(label="Sell", command=self.switch_to_sell)
```

### Example

Here is a complete working example. To keep it simple and on topic it doesn't actually switch pages. Instead, it just displays the "page" in a label.

```
import tkinter as tk

class MenuExample:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, width=25)
        self.label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)

        self._create_menubar()

    def _create_menubar(self):
        # create the menubar
        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self.root)
        self.root.configure(menu=self.menubar)

        # File menu
        fileMenu = tk.Menu(self.menubar)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.root.destroy)

        # View menu
        viewMenu = tk.Menu(self.menubar)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="View", menu=viewMenu)
        viewMenu.add_command(label="Input", command=self.switch_to_input)
        viewMenu.add_command(label="Sell", command=self.switch_to_sell)

    def switch_to_input(self):
        # put the code to switch to the input page here...
        self.label.configure(text="you clicked on View->Input")

    def switch_to_sell(self):
        # put the code to switch to the sell page here...
        self.label.configure(text="you clicked on View->Sell")

app = MenuExample()
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan Oakley, sorry for asking because I am not sure this is the place to ask it, but what is the code that switches pages, I also googled for a example for that but I didn’t find anything