# Tkinter Menu Bar in Application Title

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, customtkinter

Does anyone know how do create a menu in the application title bar for tkinter?

I tried like doing somthing like 'root.config(menu=menu)' but it stays the same

Does anyone know the answer to this, if you do please help! Thank you!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HykNk.png)

Comment: What menu bar are you referring to? "_...but it stays the same_": What stays the same. Reference images can be helpful in this situation

Comment: Are you running this app on a Macintosh? The menubar on a Mac goes where all Mac menubars go - along the top of the display.

Comment: I added the image

Comment: oh by the way Im using custom tkinter

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74842227/how-to-add-menu-bar-in-custom-tkinter

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to add a menu:

```
from tkinter import *

Root = Tk()
#Creates menu bar
Menubar = Menu(Root)
#Add different menu tabs
file_menu = Menu(Menubar, tearoff=0)
Menubar.add_cascade(label=“new tab”, menu=file_menu)

#Add different commands under a tab
file_menu.add_command(label=“new file”)
```

This link can also help: [how can I create a menuBar using tkinter in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55325508/how-can-i-create-a-menubar-using-tkinter-in-python)

Comment: OP wants to have the menubar created *in the application title bar*.

Comment: also OP is using custom tkinter not tk